# How to make an infinite foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to make a foreach loop to give players in the game gold every so often, and I tried the following:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kVP in names)
{
    player[kVP.Key].gold += 1;
    continue;
}
```

But that doesn't go infinitely. It actually gives only 1 gold, and stops.

If it helps, `names` is a `Dictionary<int, string>`.

I do realize a foreach loop never stops, but it doesnt give any gold to me.

NOTE: Everyone, I see i shouldn't use the foreach loop, but the kVP.Key is needed, because it identifies a player by its id, which is in the []s of player[]. I don't know how to get that in a another loop

Comment: You don't need to have `continue` in there :) What happens when it reaches the `continue` is that it proceeds to the next iteration of the loop -- just as if the statement had not been there! (in this case)

Comment: You do realize that an infinite loop never stops, right? Is that what you really want?

Comment: Do you already have a game loop running? It is going to have to work with the game loop. Even if you were to write an infinite loop, it is just going to run the code inside the loop forever without yielding execution to the rest of your game logic.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the purpose of running a loop constantly, even here. It seems to me that it should be a timer that interrogates some artifacts on tick and then performs the operation if necessary.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That would be true in a more traditional desktop application, but games tend to not do that, for performance reasons, and also to have much more finely grained control over timings.  (The precision of a timer is often insufficient for a game.)

Comment: I think we're messing stuff up, because the question is bound to one loop. As I read your question, it seems to me you want a infinite game loop, and in that loop increment the gold of a finite amount of players by one. The second loop is currently in your question. Wrap it in the other answers while(true) loop and you're ready I would say.

Comment: @NielsV When I do a while(true) loop, I say (in chat, which tells you your gold) .gold and nothing happens, maybe because the gold is in the while loop

Answer (score 8):

You should have a game loop, which should be running whenever the game is running.  In that loop, if it has been sufficiently long since the last time this code ran (since, presumably, you don't want this running every single iteration of the game loop, but rather every Nth iteration) you'll run this code.

And of course the `continue;` is pointless and can simply be removed.  When the end of the body is reached it already knows to go to the next iteration; you don't need to redundantly state this, not that it really hurts anything (beyond readability) either.

---

Of course, just to answer the literal question that you asked (even though it doesn't solve your problem), here is a simple extension method that you can call on a sequence in order to repeat it infinitely:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatForever<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    while (true)
        foreach (var item in sequence)
            yield return item;
}
```

Thus allowing you to write:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kVP in names.RepeatForever())
{
    player[kVP.Key].gold += 1;
}
```

to keep adding gold forever.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make an infinite `foreach` loop. `foreach` is specifically for iterating through a collection.

If that's not what you want, you should not be using `foreach`.

Comment: This is not true; you can iterate over a sequence that is infinite.

Comment: @Servy: Sure, you could use the specifics of the platform to produce such a sequence. But the purpose of it is to iterate through a collection, which is not what the OP seems to want.

Comment: @Servy The intention of foreach is to iterate a finite collection.  While what you say is technically true, foreach is not meant to be used specifically to create an infinite loop

Comment: @Taegost It's meant to iterate a sequence.  It doesn't *care* if it's finite or infinite.  If the caller wants to iterate an infinite sequence, that's *just fine*.  That's like asserting that a `while` loop is specifically to iterate a finite number of iterations.  It's meant to iterate until the condition is false, if that's never, so be it.

Comment: @JonathanWood But you don't describe how the OP *should* go about solving his problem, making this a not particularly helpful answer.  Also, the use of `foreach` here isn't inappropriate entirely; he *should* be using it to iterate the sequence once, just not infinitely.  The infinite part, in this case, belongs elsewhere.

Comment: @Taegost I'm not sure it's even technically accurate since compute resources are always finite there is no way to have a truly infinite enumerable. You can iterate though a finite enumerable infinite times, but an infinite length enumerable? Probably not.

Comment: @siva.k That's simply not the case.  You're assuming that everything that is `IEnumerable` is a collection; some sort of view of something in memory.  That's just not true.  Here's a handy truly infinite sequence worth using in a real app: `public static IEnumerable<int> Random() { Random r = new Random(); while (true)yield return r.Next(); }`

Comment: @Servy That's what I was referring to by being able to make a finite enumerable infinite.

Comment: @siva.k What is finite about it?  There is no repeated finite enumerable, there is only one infinite enumerable in that example.  You could do it explicitly, by defining your own classes instead of using an iterator block, but why would you?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding `foreach` and `continue`.

`foreach` iterates over a sequence;

```
foreach(var x in sequence)
{
    // ...
}
```

is basically (give or take some details):

```
using(var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(iter.MoveNext())
    {
        var x = iter.Current;
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `continue` keyword just jumps to the next item (if any) - i.e. it goes back to the `while`, re-testing the condition.

If you want to loop infinitely, then either:

- have an infinite loop (`while(true)` would work)
- have an infinite sequence (you can `foreach` over more than just collections)

Comment: But why would the OP want to loop forever anyway? Can't this more appropriately be done with a timer? I don't profess to be a game programmer--it just seems odd to me.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud obviously OP does not want to "loop forever" - it looks like OP needs "run code on every game loop" which is not what the question is about - [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I need it so its like background gold mines are generating gold for you, so you can buy things. That is why I need the gold to be generating infinitely.

Comment: @user that still sounds unlikely to be something that needs an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

This is one example of an infinite loop:

```
while (true) {
    // code goes here. It will be run repeatedly, over and over, forever.
}
```

That probably isn't what you want if you want something to happen periodically, however. This would happen immediately, and never finish running the code inside the `while` loop.

Comment: +1 as it answers the question in standard way (obviously OP does not want what is asked for, so should not be done in game's code).

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop is not the proper C# construct to use here. By definition, it will run once for every element of the collection it iterates over.

You should try using one of the following: for(), while() or do{} while

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is used to go through an `IEnumerable<>`.  If you're looking for an infinite loop, then try a `while(Running)` with `Running` as some sort of flag that can eventually terminate the loop.

I doubt you want to run the loop too rapidly, otherwise your players would be too rich!  So you would want to add a delay to the loop to have it run only every so often.

```
while(Running)
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeBetweenGoldHandouts);

  foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kVP in names)
    player[kVP.Key].gold += 1;
}
```

**NOTE**

`continue` is used to skip to the next iteration of the loop. Because you had it as the last entry of the loop, it is meaningless.

Comment: This would generally be fine in a more traditional UI application, but games are...different.  This approach is generally to heavy for a game platform which will use a game loop, rather than using asynchrony.

Comment: @Servy What part is "heavy"? The `async/await`?  Is this really a concern event if it is infrequent as it would be?

Comment: In a game app, yes, yes it is.  There are so many "time" based events that the number of timers (which is how `Delay` is implemented) created accumulate in their work over time and cause problems.  Additionally, such timers generally have insufficient precision for games; the control over how often an event ticks often needs to be controlled well beyond the several dozen millisecond precision you have with traditional timers.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough... I've never tried to make a game (certainly not in .NET) and have never given it any thought.

Comment: I'm not an expert in the field, by my passing context with it has given me enough information to know that all games should have a game loop, and that is the generally accepted appropriate practice for how to do something every X period of time.

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` loop is intended to iterate over a list with a finite number of elements. You do not want that to run forever. To do that, one uses a `while` or a `do`  loop.

Probably not exactly what you're looking for, but it is technically possible to have a foreach run forever. That can be achieved by writing an endless enumerator class. That, however, I would call purposedly constructed ugly code.